# Eclipselink gives validation exception

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink, mysql-workbench, netbeans-8

[image]

I used MySQLWorkbench as a modelling tool to create my db. I generated a simple testDB for testing JPA/Eclipselink, Netbeans entity and web services generator. When I generate entities and services I got an error message like this:

```
Exception Description: [class com.rako.rma.Rma] uses a non-entity [class com.rako.rma.Product] as target entity in the relationship attribute [field productserialNumberLOTN].
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.nonEntityTargetInRelationship(ValidationException.java:1378)
```

**RMA entity**

```
public class Rma implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "rma_id")
private Integer rmaId;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "temp1")
private String temp1;
@JoinColumn(name = "product_serialNumber_LOTN", referencedColumnName = "serialNumber_LOTN")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Product productserialNumberLOTN;
```

**Product entity**

```
public class Product implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 20)
@Column(name = "serialNumber_LOTN")
private String serialNumberLOTN;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "temp1")
private String temp1;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "temp2")
private String temp2;
@JoinColumn(name = "serialNumber_LOTN", referencedColumnName = "LOTN", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@OneToOne(optional = false)
private SerialNumber serialNumber;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "productserialNumberLOTN")
private Collection<Rma> rmaCollection;
```

**SerialNumber entity**

```
public class SerialNumber implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 20)
@Column(name = "LOTN")
private String lotn;
@Size(max = 45)
@Column(name = "temp")
private String temp;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "serialNumber")
private Product product;
```

**Question**

1) Did I design my db incorrectly?

2) Is the Netbeans JPA generator working properly?

3) If it's not working 100 %, how can I fix my jpa notation so that this relations are working?

Comment: Entities seem fine when I paste to a netbeans project. Whats your persistence.xml like? Can the server start up afterwards, or is it just while generating the problem is there?

Comment: When generating and server doesn't start. Netbeans 8.02 and Glassfish 4.1.

Comment: I THINK, that char as a pk is the problem. If I add one field serialNumberID as a pk and it is just auto increment int, everything is working fine. Problem is that REST-services are not working either in Netbeans (test rest) even if server is up and running, but with serialNumberID they are working...

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a problem with what you've shown, so the issue might  be that you have multiple instances of classes on your classpath somehow, so that some other version of product is picked up.  Check how it is being packaged and deployed

Comment: Check if `Product` has any lamdba expression. There is a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=429992) with it.

Answer (score 0):

Each of your entities classes need @Entity annotation on top of them:

```
@Entity
public class Product implements Serializable {
...
```

Comment: I got them, but that is not the reason in my case.